# Let A be a $5\times 5$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{n_i+n_j+1}$.Then

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix with entries  $ a_{ij} = \frac{1}{n_i+n_j+1} $,where $ n_i,n_j \in \mathbb{N} $.

Then which of the following cases $A$ is a positive definite matrix ?

1. $ n_i=i $ for all $ i=1,2,3,4,5 $
2. $ n_1< n_2< n_3 < n_4 < n_5 $
3. $ n_1=n_2=n_3=n_4=n_5 $
4. $ n_1> n_2 > n_3 > n_4 > n_5 $

For option 1, I wrote  down the matrix , tried to calculate leading principal minors which was a difficult task.

for option 2 and 4 , don't have any clue.

option 3 is trivially false.

Any hint for option 1 , 2 and 4  would be great.  THANKS

Comment: your matrix seems to be a special case of the [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix), for which there are many formulae available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac1{m+1}=\int_0^1x^m\,dx.$$
Then for constants $a_1,\ldots,a_5$, if we set $f(x)=a_1x^{n_1}+\cdots+a_5x^{n_5}$
then
$$\int_0^1f(x)^2\,dx=\sum_{i,j=1}^5a_ia_j\int_0^1 x^{n_i+n_j}\,dx
=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{a_ia_j}{n_i+n_j+1}>0$$
unless $f$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sir, Sorry for disturbing you, Is it trivial to show that if $ n_1\neq n_2\neq n_3\neq n_4\neq n_5 $ f (x) is nonidentically zero on [0,1] ?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari If a **polynomial** is not the zero polynomial, then it has finitely many zeroes.

Comment: Stupid of me,  thank you sir for answering , it is a great solution.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  How have u discarded the third option?

Comment: In 3, $f$ can be identically zero even if some of the $a_i$ are nonzero. @MittalG