# Condition for a symmetric matrix to be positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A=\left ( a_{ij} \right )_{5\times5}$ which is a $5 \times5$  matrix with entries $$a_{ij}=\frac{1}{n_{i}+n_{j}+1}$$
where $n_i,n_j \in \mathbb{N}$ where $0\leq i,j\leq 5$.Then  $A$ is positive definite if.

> $n_1> n_2 > n_3 > n_4 > n_5$

The solution i tried - The matrix formed under this condition is $$\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{n_1+n_1+1}&\frac{1}{n_1+n_2+1}  & \frac{1}{n_1+n_3+1} & \frac{1}{n_1+n_4+1} &\frac{1}{n_1+n_5+1} \\ 
\frac{1}{n_2+n_1+1} & \frac{1}{n_2+n_2+1} & \frac{1}{n_2+n_3+1} & \frac{1}{n_2+n_4+1} &\frac{1}{n_2+n_5+1} \\ 
\frac{1}{n_3+n_1+1} &  \frac{1}{n_3+n_2+1}& \frac{1}{n_3+n_3+1} &\frac{1}{n_3+n_4+1}  &\frac{1}{n_3+n_5+1} \\ 
 \frac{1}{n_4+n_1+1}& \frac{1}{n_4+n_2+1} &\frac{1}{n_4+n_3+1}  &\frac{1}{n_4+n_4+1}  &\frac{1}{n_4+n_5+1} \\ 
\frac{1}{n_5+n_1+1} &\frac{1}{n_5+n_2+1}  & \frac{1}{n_5+n_3+1} &\frac{1}{n_5+n_4+1}  & \frac{1}{n_5+n_5+1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

the above matrix is symmetric and all the entries are positive.Also we know that a symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite iff all its eigen values are positive .The other condition for  a matrix to be a positive definite is $$x^{T}Ax >0 \forall x \in \mathbb{C}$$ next i am not geting how to solve this question.

Please help

Thankyou

edited-

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3299266/42969

Comment: if you want a pure algebraic solution, you could use the criterion for principal minors along with laplace formula

Comment: any simple way to solve this question?